# Syntax highlight component for Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm developing a source-editor. I'm going into the 1.3.1 version and it's about time to get a syntax highlighter.

I want a free, easy to use, and simple syntax highlighter and it needs to be a component.
Any idea where I can get one?

Leave a comment if you need more information and I will update.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/). There is a [.NET implementation](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/), too.

Comment: Is it like, download and drag it over to the toolbar? or is it more advanced? Tried it before but they got crappy docs :/

Comment: You can either get free-of-charge or easy-to-use. I doubt that both is available ;-)

Comment: Thanks, i never noticed the one at codeplex. And the docs there are better than the ones at scintilla's official website.